# Swiper carousel not sliding in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Using `Swiper` carousel in a React App and even if slides are built and I can slide them with my mouse, it doesn't slide by itself. Any idea whi this could be?

```js
const carouselSlideFactory = ({icon, title, text}: SlideConfig, i: number) => {
    return <SwiperSlide key={icon+i}>
        <div className="area col-md-12 item">
            <div className="icon">
                <i data-icon={icon} className="icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="text">
                <h6>{title}</h6>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </SwiperSlide>
}

<Swiper
  slidesPerView={3}
  spaceBetween={60}
  autoplay
  speed={1000}
  modules={[Pagination]}
  navigation
  loop
  scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
  pagination={{ clickable: true }}
>
  { configs.map((config, i) => carouselSlideFactory(config, i)) }
</Swiper>
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide the autoplay `delay` prop as in this [e.g. sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-autoplay-m6ugi)

Comment: no @KcH that has nothing to do with the problem, neither the question.

Comment: oh is it ... Then it would be better if you can create a reproducible sample ....

Comment: I found the solution, Autoplay module has to be imported and passed to the modules array, thanks.